# create calculated column to show which column is missing

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement where I need to bring in calculated column to show if Type A, B or C is missing.

- A Service can have one to many Types (there are 10 different "Type").
- Service has to have all 3 "Type": A B and C.
- If its missing any of the 3, I need to show which "Type" is missing.

For example, if Service ID 2 has Type A then the calculated column has to say "Type B and C is missing", if Service ID 3 has Type B then the calculated column has to say Type A and C is missing" etc...

I got the calculation to say "Type A B or C is missing" but having hard time to break it down to the specific Type that is missing. I will eventually union this result to few other queries that are similar.  Can anyone help with this?

```
SELECT ri.service_id, 
       ri.name, 
       ri.creation_date, 
       'Type A B or C is missing' AS missing 
FROM   service ri 
WHERE  ri.special = 'Yes' 
  AND  ri.service_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ri.service_id 
                             FROM   service ri, 
                                    service_cust rfni, 
                                    cust rfn 
                             WHERE  ri.service_id = rfni.service_id 
                               AND  rfni.cust_id = rfn.cust_id 
                               AND  ri.special = 'Yes' 
                               AND rfn.TYPE IN( 'A', 'B', 'C' ) 


                               GROUP  BY ri.service_id 
                                 HAVING Count(DISTINCT rfn.TYPE) = 3) 

Thanks`
CREATE TABLE SERVICE
(service_id  VARCHAR(50),
name  VARCHAR( 50 ),
special  VARCHAR( 50 )
)

Insert into SERVICE (service_id,name,special) values ('1','Service1','Yes');
Insert into SERVICE (service_id,name,special) values ('2','Service2','Yes');
Insert into SERVICE (service_id,name,special) values ('3','Service3','Yes');
Insert into SERVICE (service_id,name,special) values ('4','Service4','Yes');
Insert into SERVICE (service_id,name,special) values ('5','Service5','Yes');
Insert into SERVICE (service_id,name,special) values ('6','Service6','Yes');
Insert into SERVICE (service_id,name,special) values ('7','Service7','Yes');
Insert into SERVICE (service_id,name,special) values ('8','Service8','Yes');
Insert into SERVICE (service_id,name,special) values ('9','Service9','No');





CREATE TABLE SERVICE_CUST
(cust_id  VARCHAR(50),
service_id  VARCHAR( 50 )
)

Insert into SERVICE_CUST (cust_id,service_id) values ('1','1');
Insert into SERVICE_CUST (cust_id,service_id) values ('2','1');
Insert into SERVICE_CUST (cust_id,service_id) values ('3','1');
Insert into SERVICE_CUST (cust_id,service_id) values ('4','1');
Insert into SERVICE_CUST (cust_id,service_id) values ('5','2');
Insert into SERVICE_CUST (cust_id,service_id) values ('6','3');
Insert into SERVICE_CUST (cust_id,service_id) values ('7','4');
Insert into SERVICE_CUST (cust_id,service_id) values ('8','4');
Insert into SERVICE_CUST (cust_id,service_id) values ('9','5');


CREATE TABLE CUST
(cust_id  VARCHAR(50),
type  VARCHAR( 50 )
)

Insert into CUST (cust_id,type) values ('1','A');
Insert into CUST (cust_id,type) values ('2','B');
Insert into CUST (cust_id,type) values ('3','C');
Insert into CUST (cust_id,type) values ('4','D');
Insert into CUST (cust_id,type) values ('5','A');
Insert into CUST (cust_id,type) values ('6','B');
Insert into CUST (cust_id,type) values ('7','A');
Insert into CUST (cust_id,type) values ('8','B');
Insert into CUST (cust_id,type) values ('9','F');
```

when I run this query

```
select ri.service_id, ri.name, rfn.type
from service ri, service_cust rfni, cust rfn
where ri.service_id = rfni.service_id
and rfni.cust_id = rfn.cust_id 
and  ri.special = 'Yes'
```

I get

1   Service1    A 1 Service1    B 1 Service1    C 1 Service1    D 2 Service2    A    3  Service3    B 4 Service4    A 4 Service4    B 5 Service5    F

I only need Services that is missing Type A,B or C.  If it has all 3 (A,B,C) then don't need to see in results.
so results i am looking for is 
Service2 with text 'Missing B,C'
Service3 with text 'Missing A,C'
Service4 with text 'Missing C'

i think my 1st part of the original query is not working properly as its bringing in:Service 2,3,4,5,6,7 and 8

```
select  ri.service_id, ri.name
from service ri 
where ri.special = 'Yes'
and ri.service_id not in (
select distinct ri.service_id
from service ri, service_cust rfni, cust rfn
where ri.service_id = rfni.service_id
and rfni.cust_id = rfn.cust_id 
and  ri.special = 'Yes'
and rfn.type in( 'A','B', 'C')
group by ri.service_id
having count(distinct rfn.type)=3)
```

thanks for help

`

Comment: Could you put together a small reproducible example ? The scripts to : create a table to to mimic your business problem and a couple of rows to enter data and the result you're looking for.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  You have three tables in the `FROM`.  We have no idea what they contain.  And why aren't you using proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: sorry took so long to create data.  here is sample table and records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a conditional aggregate query to count the occurrence of types:

```
SELECT ri.service_id,
       ri.name,
       ri.creation_date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rfn.TYPE = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TypeA_Count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rfn.TYPE = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TypeB_Count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rfn.TYPE = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TypeC_Count
FROM   service ri
LEFT JOIN service_cust rfni 
     ON ri.service_id = rfni.service_id 
LEFT JOIN cust rfn
     ON rfni.cust_id = rfn.cust_id 
WHERE  ri.special = 'Yes' 
  AND  rfn.TYPE IN( 'A', 'B', 'C' ) 
GROUP  BY ri.service_id,
          ri.name,
          ri.creation_date
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT rfn.type) < 3
```

And if needing to return a single column, integrate above in a CTE:

```
WITH cte (
   ...same as above...
)

SELECT cte.service_id,
       cte.name,
       cte.creation_date,
       CASE 
            WHEN TypeA_Count = 0 AND TypeB > 0 AND TypeC_Count > 0 THEN 'Type A is Missing'
            WHEN TypeA_Count = 0 AND TypeB = 0 AND TypeC_Count > 0 THEN 'Type A and B are Missing'
            WHEN TypeA_Count = 0 AND TypeB > 0 AND TypeC_Count = 0 THEN 'Type A and C are Missing'
            WHEN TypeA_Count > 0 AND TypeB = 0 AND TypeC_Count > 0 THEN 'Type B is Missing'
            WHEN TypeA_Count > 0 AND TypeB = 0 AND TypeC_Count = 0 THEN 'Type B and C are Missing'
            WHEN TypeA_Count > 0 AND TypeB > 0 AND TypeC_Count = 0 THEN 'Type C is Missing'
            WHEN TypeA_Count > 0 AND TypeB > 0 AND TypeC_Count > 0 THEN 'None are Missing'
       END Missing
FROM cte
```

Comment: My answer is very similiar, so I will delete it, but leave [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1f0bca7e7769151ba1058b53ce4b9367), it may be useful.

Comment: thanks @parfait,  using your 1st sql, I am getting back Service 1 which should not come back since it has TypeA, B and C.  is there a way to exclude if Type is in all A, B and C?  I ran query without creation date(forgot to add to table but don't need it)

Comment: Try adjusting your original `HAVING` clause: `having count(distinct rfn.type) < 3)`.

Comment: thanks Parfait.  That was my mistake as i didn't put there.  Thanks for your help, at least my base query works.  trying out your second sql as i need to add final query to bunch of other queries in a union, so hoping I can union the final query I get here to my other queries...Appreciate the help

Comment: Understood. Remember you can have many CTEs referencing each other in one statement.

Comment: Wow, that worked.  I just need to bring in about 10 more column from the Service table, I didn't bring in my example since there was lot of grouping going on and didn't want to over complicate example.  Is there way to bring in the the one calculation with the 10 more columns from the Service table?  So ri.service_id, calculation, ri.col2, ri.col3, ri.col4 ri.col5 etc...? thanks

Comment: Not quite clear what you mean but maybe you should ask a new question with all needed details?